# Write the function $f(x) = 0, \text{if $x \leq 0$}; x, \text{if $x > 0$}$ as a single formula using the absolute value sign.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, absolute-value

I found this exercise in Demidovich's "Problems in Mathematical Analysis", and found it quite interesting.

> Write the function
>   $$
> f(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> 0, & \text{if $x \leq 0$} \\
> x, & \text{if $x > 0$}
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   as a single formula using the absolute value sign.

I've posted my solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Answer

### $$f(x) = \frac{x + \lvert x \rvert}{2}$$

---

### Explanation

When $x \leq 0$, $x + \lvert x\rvert = 0$, rendering the $\text{RHS} = 0$.

When $x > 0$, $x + \lvert x \rvert = 2x$. So, it must be divided by $2$ for $\text{RHS} = x$.

Answer (score 2):

It seems natural to generalize this problem to:

> Write the function
>   $$
> f_{ab}(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> ax, & \text{if $x \leq 0$} \\
> bx, & \text{if $x > 0$}
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   as a single formula using the absolute value sign.

Having done so:

- Notice that the slope of $f_{ab}$ jumps by $(b-a)$ at $0$; $f_{ab}$ is smooth elsewhere. The slope of the absolute value function changes by $2$ at $0$, suggesting that we consider the function
  $$
  g_{ab}(x)=f_{ab}(x)-\frac{b-a}{2}|x|
  $$
  which will "smooth out" $f$ at $0$.
- Having noticed this, it's not too hard to check by case analysis that in fact
  $$
  g_{ab}(x)=\frac{b+a}{2}x
  $$
  and so
  $$
  f_{ab}(x)=\frac{b+a}{2}x + \frac{b-a}{2}|x| 
  $$

When $a=0$ and $b=1$ as in the original problem, this reduces to the solution in the other answer.